# How to remove 2 last characters with preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-group, substr

I have a code like : 784XX . XX could be a character or number and I need an expression to remove the last 2 characters (XX) using ( and only ) `preg_replace`.

How can I do that?

For example, the output of :

```
782A3 is 782,

0012122 is 00121,

76542A is 7654,

333333CD is 333333,
```

Comment: `substr('784XX', 0, -2)`

Comment: An exotic one for very Unicode-ish strings - `preg_replace('/\X{2}\z/u', '', $s)`

Comment: What if there is a CRLF at the end, need to remove them ? Or, it could be non-printable, or some strange combining characters or other dubious stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substr` function.

But if you will use preg_replace you can do this:

```php
$val = preg_replace('/[\w\d]{2}$/', '', $val);
```

Comment: Why the strange class `[\w\d]`?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Quote from the question: "XX could be a character or number"

Comment: And what contains the `\w` class?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there are much easier ways to do this task, yet if we wish to use regular expressions, we would be starting with just a simple expression such as:

```
(.+)?(..)
```

if I understand the problem right, and our desired output is in this capturing group:

```
(.+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/e6vshy/1/)

```
$re = '/(.+)?(..)/m';
$str = '782A3
0012122
76542A
333333CD';
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Advice

[AbraCadaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2844319/abracadaver)'s advice in the comment is much better way:

```
substr('784XX', 0, -2);
```